# OpenCV, backwards slashes in path?

Tags: python, opencv, path

Here's the error I'm receiving in the terminal, and I thought "hm that's weird why are the slashes going different directions in the path?"

```
[ WARN:0@18.822] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/summer research/programming\tmp-udr\00000001.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
```

Anyone seen this before? I'm trying to update something that was originally written in python 2.7, so maybe that's the problem or OpenCV is just being strange.

I'm fairly new to python but I'm trying my best.

The code has over 1000 lines and it wasn't written by me so I'm not sure how helpful I can be, I'm mostly just modifying it to fit my use and I honestly have no idea how this error could even happen.

I think this may be the problem but I'm not sure

```
def getTrainedModel(generalsamples, generalresponses):
  samples = np.loadtxt(resource_path(str(generalsamples)),np.float32)
  responses = np.loadtxt(resource_path(str(generalresponses)),np.float32)
  responses = responses.reshape((responses.size,1))
  model = cv2.ml.KNearest_create()
  model.train(samples,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,responses)
  return model
```

Any information would be a godsend, thank you.

Comment: In windows you can mox forward and backward slashes, but in strings you have to make sure that a backslash is correctly used in a string (because a backslash is also used for escape characters)

Comment: The sequence `\a` in a Python string literal is an escape for the ascii BEL character, byte value 7, which actually used to ring the bell of a Teletype terminal. To convey the 2-character sequence `\a`, code either `r"\a"` or `"\\a"`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV wants forward slashes (`'/a/b/c'`), OR raw strings (`r'a\b\c'`)

Try putting an r before your string where you load it with opencv. You are looking for a `cv2.imread()` call, or some other data loader function wrapping it.

E.g.:
`cv2.imread('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/summer research/programming\tmp-udr\00000001.jpg')` -> `cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/summer research/programming\tmp-udr\00000001.jpg')`

Your filename might be a variable, in that case you can use `fr'{variable_name}'` (an f-string that is a raw string), or, if your python version does not yet support f-strings, use `r"{}".format(variable_name)`.

Even better would be to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to create a `Path` object and use `.as_posix()` when passing it to OpenCV.

Comment: I appreciate you answering so quickly! Is there a way to essentially just put the r before it, if it is a variable and not a string? I really have a difficult time understanding how to use imported things so I would like to avoid that at all costs if possible ;-; new to python lol

Comment: I am tempted to just set the variable to the path string and call it a day but I want to try to make this functional for other people as well lol

Comment: Yes, I just edited my answer with exactly that case. f-strings are the way to go (if your python version supports it. If not, try `r"{}".format(variable_name)`.

Comment: @SageCrosby The `r` prefix is only needed in a string literal. Once the backslash is in the variable it is safely there as a backslash. You only need escapes in string literals because there is no convenient way to type nonprinting characters between the quotes.